# php compare difference between two dates

Tags: php, date

Im trying to return the difference between 2 dates, i'm working according to the [example found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

My Problem? Im getting completely the wrong results returned, the following code returns 30 years, 0 months, 9 days, when it should obviously be only 7 days or 1 week.

Code follows below:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

    $pickupDate = '2016-10-13';
    $returnDate  = 2016-10-20;

    $diff = abs(strtotime($pickupDate) - strtotime($returnDate));
    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Any input appreciated

Comment: Use PHP's built-in date functions, don't do naive hours*days calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put single quote in return date like `$returnDate  = '2016-10-20';` and you can use `date_diff()` function of php like,

```
$daysdiffernce = date_diff(date_create('2016-10-13'),date_create('2016-10-20'));
echo $daysdiffernce->format("%R%a days");
```

and this will give exactly +7days answer

Comment: Worked like a charm; everyday you learn something new `date_diff()` Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, the code doesn't take into account leap years, varying length of months and things like that.

There is actually a function in php for this, please check the link for details: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php , and an example taken:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-10-13');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2016-10-20');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will give you differ in date, and , time, minutes, hour ,second ,and etc.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$now = '2016-10-13';
$returnDate  = '2016-10-20';
$start = date_create($returnDate);
$end = date_create($now);
$diff=date_diff($end,$start);
print_r($diff);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/P2oPB)**

Answer (score 1):

From the manual

```
 $pickupDate = new DateTime('2016-10-13');
 $returnDate = new DateTime('2016-10-20');
 $interval = $pickupDate->diff($returnDate);
 echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$pickupDate = '2016-10-13';
$returnDate  = '2016-10-20'; //use signle quote same as pickupDate 

$diff = abs(strtotime($returnDate) - strtotime($pickupDate)); // change the order 
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Thanks